# what commonly happens when a database getByPrimaryKey function fails to find a record?

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, architecture, model

I am writing a MVC application but i cannot use any existing library. I am trying to decide what should happen when my `getRecordByPrimaryKey` function finds 0 records and what to do when it finds > 1 record. People can search by primary key in the application so I do not know if it makes sense to throw an exception when none is found.

How do most libraries handle this scenario? Should it return an array of objects and the calling code needs to verify there is 1 and only 1 record, or should it return a single object?  What should it return if no objects are found, NULL or throw exception? And if > 1 record is found? Exception?

Answer (score 0):

The home-grown MVC frameworks I have used in the past generally return null.  Throwing an exception is expensive at runtime and it's fairly easy for a developer to remember to check for null.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written your database constraint correctly, you will never have a duplicate primary key.

In the case of a corresponding record not being found - if this is something that is an expected and normal occurrence for your application, then an error message informing the user is the right thing to do.

However, if you have written your application so such an occurrence should never happen, an exception is probably more appropriate. Again, informing the user is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is very subjective and each approach have its cons and pros.

**Returning NULL**

- Good: Fast and straightforward
- Good: Probably the most natural thing to do
- Bad: Requires additional checking for not-NULL-ness

**Throwing an exception**

- Good: Clearly communicates out about error
- Bad: Not the best way to provide feedback
- Bad: Usually very slow

**Returning empty instance (stub)**

- Good: Fulfills the expectation for an object
- Good: Allows reusing returned object when not found
- Bad: Some programmers will go like "WTF?"
- Bad: Slower than returning NULL

I personally tend to use approach #3. It has the advantage of being super strict with expectations set by method name: if it says it returns object of class Foo by primary key, than it should return that object no matter what - be it primary key not found, database down, or server on fire.
It also allows using nice shortcuts and reuse of returned object (example in PHP):

```
$foo = Foo::getByPrimaryKey(12345);
if (!$foo->exists()) { // no need for checking for NULL
    $foo->name = 'bar';
    $foo->colour = 'baz';
    $foo->save(); // create it on the spot
}
echo $foo->name; // use it like it was always there
```

Also, `$foo->exists()` is more conversational in style. One may downplay the importance of keeping the code close to natural language, or even call it childish. My take is that the farther you stay from manipulating ones, zeros, data types, exceptions, and all that computer related nonsense, the better for your program.

As per your question in relation to rows count - keep it safe in the input, so you don't have to worry about it at point of retrieval. Use database constraints to make it impossible to enter duplicate rows. And again, keep it consistent with the promise you made by naming your method "getByPrimaryKey" - primary key by definition is unique, hence returning multiple rows/objects would be an offence to common sense.